# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in index.php on line 2

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, xampp, wordpress-theming

having same issue, i am totally new in php. i install XAMPP then download hatch theme from wordpress. when i run index.php its gives me following error

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hatch\index.php on line 1"

can anyone help about this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have wordpress installed and then you can apply the theme. As far as I know you can't run WP themes by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you need to have wordpress installed then move your files to the theme folder as follows:
wp-content/themes/yourwebsitefiles